# Accessing ejs variables from js file

Tags: node.js, express

I have this code in my subcategory.js file. Is there any way to get the variable ?

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('<%= id %>') > -1){
    var ele=document.getElementById('toggle1');
    ele.innerHTML = "<a href='/cat/<%= id %>'>"+'<%= id %>'+"</a>";
    ele.style.display="block";
}

$('[id^="c"]').each(function(i){
    $('#c'+i).attr('action', '/subcat/<%= sp[2] %>/' + i);
});
```

Comment: What variable, and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: <%= sp[2] %> , <%= id %> ,trying to get the code to work, these 2 variables are unidentified in subcategory.js,however,if i put the code into subcategory.ejs,it works fine

Comment: You can try with `<%- JSON.stringify(myVar) %>`. Note the `<%-` instead of the `<%=`